# fill html input field and tedit same time

Tags: delphi, edit, twebbrowser

I want to create a form with a twebbrowser and a tedit box, more if needed.

Then lets say, I want the browser to be on google.com and when I type in the search bar I want it to type in the tedit as well. Best would be at the same time but it is fine if i click away it will fill in the tedit box as well. i just want to understand how this work, Type on the site and have the edit boxed automatically typed as well.

anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no event in `TWebBrowser` (so far as I know) that fires as you edit the location (I don't think `TWebBrowser` has a search bar so I presume that's what you mean).

When I have tried to keep a host app in sync with a `TWebBrowser` I have used the `OnBeforeNavigate2` event.

Comment: no i dont mean the search bar. i mean the search bar on the google.com website. I want to type anything in it and that it appears also in a seperate edit box or memo....

Comment: @ployo60 You don't get events as you type into fields on a website like that.

Comment: @ployo60 Why don't you tell us your ultimate goal. You can't hook `OnChange` like events of in-page fields with TWebBrowser unless I am very much mistaken. So, perhaps it's time for a major rethink of your project. But I've no idea what that is!!

Comment: ok i want to keep a record of my last 10 searches in google. When I type my prefered search word in the input field on the site in the twebbrowser. I want to click a button which copies the word or words in the input field on the website and pastes it in a memobox underneath eachother. but im taking it step by step, so i wanted to know that first bit. getting the typed info from the site into an edit box or a memo box, that doesnt matter so much but its the code behind it i'm interested in

Comment: @ployo60 OK, forget about a a separate edit control. Just listen to OnBeforeNavigate2 and read the new URL each time. If it's a google search, then extract the search query from the URL and log it. Job done!

Comment: ok fair enough. makes sense, and I agree this is a way to do it. But what if I want to copy it from a different input field on a website. Lets say a comment field or a username and password field or anything that doesnt show up in the url. That it coppies the information that is typed in that into a memobox.

Comment: @ployo60 Well in that case you'd be writing malware. I think I've answered your question, so if you want to ask some more then I think it's probably worth a new question.

Comment: @ployo60 If you really want to manipulate fields on a web page as the user browses then you want to be doing it somewhere that exposes the DOM. The obvious route is through a browser extension and not Delphi/TWebBrowser.

Comment: yeah, thought of that too, except i have no experience at all with browser extensions and i dont know where to start, what language it is in, which browser to chose :P I'm not trying to create malware, just something for myself, i have no interest in hacking sites or creating bots that just make millions of emails. although i think if i understood that i would be to help. but thx for your interest anyways. appreciate it

Comment: @ployo60 have a go at a Firefox extension; it's very easy and there will be lots of simple examples and tutorials; it would be fun!!

Comment: ok ill look into that as well, still gonna try to find a way to get it working this as well. ill just have to use that for my own personal browser

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but I bookmarked the web site a while ago.

[Calling into Delphi from JavaScript](http://www.delphidabbler.com/articles?article=22&part=4#calling-delphi)

The article discusses how to call delphi-code from the TWebBrowser.  You implements an external object extension by declaring an interface, and then registers it with the browser control.  Doing that, you should be able to invoke delphi methods by using JavaScript in the web site.

You have to be in control of the source that is shown in the TWebBrowser, so the google example wouldn't work.   ...unless you manipulate the html-source by injecting custom code before you show it in the TWebBrowser, of cource.

I hope this may put you the right track...

Answer (score 0):

Reading [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878967/fill-html-input-field-and-tedit-same-time/4879109#4879109), you may consider to do it the other way around:

Type the search in the TEdit (and handle all the logging you need), and then navigate the TWebBrowser to this url:  `'http://www.google.com/search?q=' + Edit1.Text`

Comment: yeah i thought of that as well. but thats not what i wanted, to say it in a rude way. I really want to create a list of things typed in on the site and that being saved in a box....  that way you can keep your twebbrowser on full size and best usable.